# rem px in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, measurement

I use this code in JS:

`bigPhoto.setAttribute("width", "200rem");`

The result is in pixel in html source,

[image]

But:

[image]

When I change it to **20rem** the photo become really small.

I couldn't solve the problem which is mentioned in the photos.

Comment: Do you mean `rem` or `em` ?

Comment: The inspector will always show pixel width - that doesn't mean that you haven't specified `rem`. Apparently, your base font size is `10px` so that `20rem = 200px`

Comment: rem: relative em.

rem is depend on device and it is suggested to use if the website is for any different devices with different density.
for the project  that I should write, I am supposed to use DOM so I used JS to set the width but rem in js doesn't work .
We couldn't tell that  20rem = 200px in all devices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The HTML width attribute only takes an integer number of pixels or a percentage (followed by a % sign).

If you wish to use CSS length units you have to use CSS (and set `bigPhoto.style.width = "200rem"`.

Answer (score 266):

Another method would be to convert rem into pixels:

```
function convertRemToPixels(rem) {    
    return rem * parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
}
```

This can be useful when you must perform some arithmetic in js (such as using the position of the mouse to display a tooltip...)

Comment: This is a great answer. `getComputedStyle` is supported also by IE11

Comment: i used hidden element to calc 1 rem, but this answer is great

Comment: Very useful! Small nitpick: Casting the input `rem` with `parseFloat(rem)` would also allow for a value that contains the `rem` unit in it.

Comment: Thanks. I could get the rem information on a webpage. By entering "getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize" in the console of developer tools. And you can get the rem in Px.

Comment: @Julien It would only parse the number portion of the string '123rem', as 123, not to calculate how much each rem unit is in px.

Comment: Is there equivalent for Node.js?

Comment: @AliEXE There's no CSS in node enviorment.