# Setting the text width on dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have created a tab component, the one part which I am not able to achieve is that, instead of TabIndicator to entirely take the length of the tab container I need to set only the text width.

Since each text has different width I am using js to calculate it, but instead of getting the width, I am able to get the container width.

How can I make the active TabIndicator line only expand from the start of the text to the end of text.

I am able to achieve the container width. Adding the sandbox link for the same.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-cerf-bfb0f)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. You need to subtract extra paddings while calculating the start and width of the indicator.
.tab has 6px padding horizontally
.tab-default-container has 1rem padding on desktop it's 16px
.
So change code something like:

```js
if (tabMeta && tabsMeta) {
 startValue = tabMeta.left - tabsMeta.left + tabsMeta.scrollLeft + 22; //16+6=22
}

//22 from both sides = 44px tor remove.
const newIndicatorStyle = {
   left: startValue,
   width: tabMeta ? tabMeta.width - 44 : 0
};
```

Updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-feather-rhsfk?file=/src/Tabs/Tabs.js:1560-1781).
**Note:** You've used relative unit `rem` it may evaluate different on different settings and devices, it may not be 1rem=16px.

> The rem (for “root em”) is the font size of the root element of the document.

So do the calculations considering this.

Comment: Thanks, just one doubt, if i need to calculate it dynamically how should I do it ?

Comment: I think this should do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42769683/15273968

Comment: No i was referring to the extra paddings part, as of now we are subtracting - 44, how can I get this with js in the sandbox which I have tried, I am able to get the container width not the exact text width

Comment: for me these changes worked    startValue = tabMeta.left - tabsMeta.left + tabsMeta.scrollLeft + 16; , width: tabMeta ? tabMeta.width - 32 : 0,

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle(tab.children[0]).paddingLeft` gives `16px` string. You can use it after parsing it to float/integer.

Comment: My browser is hanging on the sandbox. React is recursively updating dom..

Comment: On which case, when using window.getComputedStyle or just subtracting 32 and adding 16 ?

Comment: While adding use it as it is and while subtracting multiply it with 2.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-glitter-2leic, i am not able to see the browser getting hang on this changes startValue = tabMeta.left - tabsMeta.left + tabsMeta.scrollLeft + 16; 
 width: tabMeta ? tabMeta.width - 32 : 0,