# How to: Subtract a CSS value from a JS variable height?

Tags: javascript, css, function, variables, padding

How can I **subtract** from the **navbar_height** for example ****2rem**** in the following function?

```
navbar_height = document.querySelector(".navbar").offsetHeight;
document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + "px";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Explain why this is needed. Maybe there is a simpler solution.

Comment: @AndreiFedorov My navbar is position-fixed, so the navbar_height adds a padding-top to the body so as not to obscure any content. Now the style of my navbar is as follows: padding: 2rem 0;

-> 2rem under the navbar break up the symmetrical layout

hope you could follow me :)

Comment: Are you looking to convert the [`rem` into px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532307/rem-px-in-javascript)

Comment: @LeoDog896 No. Only to substract from the navbar_height 2rem, because 2rem are the padding of the fixed navbar and without subtract this my symmetrical layout would be damaged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```
navbar_height = document.querySelector(".navbar").offsetHeight;
document.body.style.paddingTop = `calc(${navbar_height}px - 2rem)`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize)` to get the rem value:

```js
let rem = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
console.log(rem);
```